Faded Bar on Frame-top in Camera View
I made a new scene. Utilizing a volumetric mesh, transparent node set up (with ambient occlusion nodes), and 3D scans. But in camera, you can see a faint bar going across the top. Mainly seen in the windows (transparent glass) where an HDRi is visible, BUT also faintly in the other renders as well. Look at all 3 images to get an idea. The first 2 are the same, one without the volumetrics, and one without. The third image is necessary to show that its not just the windows with transparency, but everywhere in the scene...
Not sure what may be causing this with all the factors, but does anyone else know what could be causing this?
(With Volume mesh)

Without Volume Mesh
Random Progress Render sample:

(Without Volume Mesh)
You can see that even when the camera isn't angled toward the windows, you can still see a faint line going though the top frame... What can I do to fix this?
